# Difference between attaching React portal directly to DOM node vs to a detached node?

Tags: reactjs

Regarding React portals, what is the difference between creating a detached node then appending it to the document vs directly having the portal rendered into the document?

In the docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) the following is there as an example. On mount, a dynamically created DOM node (`this.el`) is appended to the portal div. But what's the difference between just appending it directly to the `modalRoot` element in the document? I don't quite get the commented section of the code.

```js
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // The portal element is inserted in the DOM tree after
    // the Modal's children are mounted, meaning that children
    // will be mounted on a detached DOM node. If a child
    // component requires to be attached to the DOM tree
    // immediately when mounted, for example to measure a
    // DOM node, or uses 'autoFocus' in a descendant, add
    // state to Modal and only render the children when Modal
    // is inserted in the DOM tree.
    modalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    modalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      this.props.children,
      this.el
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think because you are using the DOM API and the React VDOM API. So, the first time the `this.el` existe but only in the DOM tree but no in the VDOM tree. It is part of react once is rendered (when you create the portal) and now you can append that node. I see `createPortal` like a `createFragmente`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's all about descendant components.

In the example above, `componentDidMount` will be called, after all descendants has mounted, and only after that, all descendants will be attached to the dom.

But you can have some logic in descendants, which requires them to be in dom.

For example, you can have child component which uses ref to calculate self position in the document, this can be done only if ref is attached to real dom.

Second example, your child input can do autofocus in `componentDidMount`. This also will take effect, only of component is already in real dom.

In these cases, you need to prevent children from rendering, until `this.el` will be attached to the dom

Comment: thanks, let me try to explain it back to you to see if i got it: Essentially, when you need to perform an operation which is only valid if an element is in the DOM (e.g. measuring a `div`), you need to use the detached DOM technique and perform those operations right after attaching them to the DOM in `componentDidMount`, otherwise you don't have certainty that they are in the DOM. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually sorry I guess I'm still confused -_-. I was able to access a child components DOM height in the useEffect without having to use the detached DOM node technique https://codepen.io/talhaguy/pen/BaLKaXb. Maybe I'm still missing the point?

Comment: @Talha you are right, you need to render children only after `this.el` is appended to the `modalRoot`, if you want to do some DOM required actions. As for accessing child height, its possible, because it doesn't require child to be strictly in the DOM, but the dimensions can be wrong, because element can be shrinked by other elements on the page, also if you want to measure its position in the viewport (e.g `getBoundingClientRect()`), you need element to be in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

With `appendChild`, the child element belongs to the same DOM and virtual DOM tree as the container. It will be affected by all cascading behaviors such as events or styles.

The Portal allows you to manage the child in a separate branch of the virtual DOM, where you have more granular control.

Simple example: if your child is a tooltip, the Portal allows you to consistently style it regardless of the container styles.